# Giving each student a set of questions so that any two would have minimal number of common questions

Tags: combinatorics, optimization

I need to create an algorithm that would give a set of questions to each student based on students` majors, number of students, possible questions.

- I am hosting an exam for my students.
- Each student has been studying 1 or more majors and has to be asked questions about them (each combination of majors corresponds to distribution of questions.) E.G. Student_1 studies math and will be asked 10 math-related questions. Student_2 studied linguistics and will be asked 12 linguistics-related questions. Student_3 studied both math and linguistics and will be asked 6 math- and 6 linguistics-related questions.
- I have a function(sudents_name) that gives me number of questions for each topic.
- I have a map (1 to many) student -> majors.
- I have a map (1 to many) question -> majors.
- At the same time N students attend the exam.
- I have to give each student questions based on their majors and minimise number questions students have in common for every pair. MIN(MAX(OVERLAP(A,B))

I have tried incorporating Multidimensional assignment problem; linear assignment problem; assignment problem, when jobs are available more then once; circuit flow problem and some variations of the last, but couldn't figure out how to adapt them for my needs. The closest on I've got was this problem:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4765015/algorithm-for-fairly-assigning-tasks-to-workers-based-on-skills

But it searches for the opposite of what I am trying to find and with some significant differences.

Comment: Welcome to mse! Is there a reason you decided to ask this here instead of, say, stackoverflow? It sounds like you're looking for a solution to a coding problem, and your question would likely fit better over there.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor I do not need a code, only an algorythm, so it felt more suited here.